# SQL Procedure with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mysql-workbench

I am new to SQL. I need to create a procedure that returns a number of orders for each customer.
I have a 'customers' table and an 'orders' table. Both tables are in the same database "shop".

In the end I need to get an array of all customers and the number of orders was placed.
this is what I have, somthing I'm doing wrong, i have an error with wrong syntax

```
CREATE PRODIDURE customers.total_count(IN id INT)

    BEGIN 
    SELECT COUNT 
    FROM orders AS order_count INNER JOIN as order_count
    ON customers.id= orders.id
    WHERE contacts.id = id 
    END
```

another question - can I call for the procedure within  NodeJS?

pls advice the correct syntax for it

```
export function getCustomers(){
const [result] = await shop.execute(    ???????     )
return result
 }
```

pls help

Comment: You say there is an error but to not say what the error is. There is also a typo `PRODIDURE`

Comment: the error is that the syntax is wrong

Comment: Please put the exact error message in the question

Answer (score 1):

To call SQL procedures from within NodeJS, you need to use an sql library. In this example from some of my own projects, I am using the MySQL library and connection pools.

```
const query = "CALL StoredProcedureName(?, ?);"
sql.query(query, [variable1, variable2], function(result, error) {
  if (error) {
    //do something with the error
    return;
  }
  //do something here with result
})
```

The example I've given above avoids sql injection by replacing the question marks with the variables inside the brackets.